# EDIT method doesn't work after adding new row

Tags: tableview, javafx-2

I would like to start editing after adding new row into TableView.

I copied example from Oracle website: [Using JavaFX UI Controls - 13 Table View](http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/ui_controls/table-view.htm#CJAGDAHE). Then I put additional button for adding new row and define action for the button.

```
final Button addButton = new Button("Add");
addButton.setOnAction(new EventHandler<ActionEvent>() {

    @Override
    public void handle(ActionEvent arg0) {
        Person p = new Person("", "", "");
        table.getItems().add(p);                
        table.getSelectionModel().select(p);
        table.edit(table.getSelectionModel().getSelectedIndex(), table.getColumns().get(2));
    }
});
```

In result I can see selected new row but the table doesn't start edditing in the third column.

I have similar method for editing existing rows and it works properly.

```
final Button editButton = new Button("Edit");
editButton.setOnAction(new EventHandler<ActionEvent>() {

    @Override
    public void handle(ActionEvent arg0) {
        table.edit(table.getSelectionModel().getSelectedIndex(), table.getColumns().get(2));
    }
});
```

Could you help me what I do wrong?

Comment: How did you solve this issue? I am also facing same issue with table view edit()